# Find a string in a file based on a pattern and replace it with something else

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a file, I want to find a specific content(lines or lines) based on a string pattern, make changes to it, and replace it. The pattern can appear multiple times.
The file can contain code, (python or c).

The string pattern can have multiple forms so I thought using regex, like:

```
custom_log("lorem ipsum can be anything ....")
```

or

```
custom_log("lorem ipsum"
           "can be anything")
```

or

```
custom_log("""lorem ipsum
           can be anything""")
```

The quotes can be simple or double.

I start by going line by line, and search for a pattern

```
with open(filepath, mode="r") as f:
  for line in f.readlines():
       if "pattern" in line
```

but the issue, is that the content that I search it can be one one line or multiple lines, and between quotes can be anything as a string.

I can't use a simple replace, because I need to get the content, passed to a function, change/adapt the content and pass it back to be written to file.

I want to keep the initial formatting of the file.

Comment: can you give a bit more information.. I am finding it hard to understand what exactly you need..  eg:- add the file contents for a bit more reference ..

Comment: Is the file small enough that you can reasonably read the entire contents into a string?

Comment: @Austin i think replace is not feasible cause the pattern is different maybe?

Comment: @yatishKadam, the file that I want to manipulate contains code, can be python, c or bash

Comment: @JohnGordon  maximum 5000 lines

Comment: Create pool of possiblities and search/repalce all.

Comment: Just a thought: using the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) you can look at what bytecode your Python code produces. String literals will always result in `LOAD_CONST` commands with any formatting syntax (line breaks / quotation marks etc.) removed. And that should be a lot easier to match a regex against. Try: `python -m dis yourfile.py`. Works only for Python code ofc.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with regex101.com? When asking this type of question, it's advisable to use a service like pastebin.com to show a real sample of what you are scanning, and what you want to extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question needs more concrete examples of what is desired, so I'll give an example where a match and replacement could span multiple lines.

Given the following sample input, `sample.txt`:

```
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
the quick
brown fox
jumped over
the lazy dog
```

The following code will replace certain pairs of words even if broken across lines using `re.sub` and a `lambda` function for processing the replacement:

```
import re

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

def replace(m):
    return ''.join([c if c.isspace() else '*'
                    for c in m.group(0)])

data = re.sub(r'quick\s+brown|over\s+the',replace,data)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
the ***** ***** fox jumped **** *** lazy dog
the *****
***** fox
jumped ****
*** lazy dog
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.sub(pattern,replacement,data,flags=re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
```

pattern = regex pattern

replacement = the new replacement string

data = original data

Answer (score 0):

We can build a regex that will look for the words of the text we are looking for, separated by any number of `\n`, spaces, or quotes. We will also make a group of the whole part between parentheses in order to make it a group that we'll keep in the replaced version.

So, the code could be:

```
import re

test = '''custom_log("some text")
custom_log("lorem ipsum can be anything")
some more text
custom_log(some text)
custom_log("lorem ipsum"
           "can be anything") 
some more text
custom_log(some text)
custom_log("""lorem ipsum
           can be anything""")
some more text'''

search = 'lorem ipsum can be anything'

# we look for 'custom_log('' followed by our search text followed by ')'
words = search.split()
search_re = r'custom_log(\("+'  + r'''[\n "]+'''.join(words) + r'"+\))'
# Our regex will be: 
# custom_log(\("+lorem[\n "]+ipsum[\n "]+can[\n "]+be[\n "]+anything"+\))

print(re.sub(search_re, r'log.info\1.base', test) + "\n")
```

Output:

```
custom_log("some text")
log.info("lorem ipsum can be anything").base
some more text
custom_log(some text)
log.info("lorem ipsum"
           "can be anything").base 
some more text
custom_log(some text)
log.info("""lorem ipsum
           can be anything""").base
some more text
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but it sounds like it.
The way I understood your question, you want to replace any string that matches a certain regular expression with a replacement string. If so this should solve it

```py
# Solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58979795/find-a-string-in-a-file-based-on-a-pattern-and-replace-it-with-something-else
# Import python regex module
import re


def replace_by_pattern(pattern: str, contents: str, replacement: str) -> str:
    matches = re.findall(pattern, contents) # Get all strings that match the pattern

    # Loop through all matches
    for match in matches:
        # Replace the first substring match with the replacement
        contents = contents.replace(match, replacement, 1)

    # Return the filtered strings
    return contents


# Define a test string
text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
"""

# Print out the result
print(replace_by_pattern(', ', text, ' - '))
```

I hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score -1):

I once has to do this exact same thing and i did it this way:

```
import os
file = open('file_path', "r")
data = file.read()
file.close()

data = data.replace('the pattern you are looking for', 'the pattern you want instead')

file = open('file_path',"w")
file.write(data)
file.close()
```

I suggest you to first do it in another file before overwritting the same file to test that works correctly. If the file is really big it will be slow, in that case you can split he file many or do readlines() in bucle with the same idea

```
data = f.readlines()
data = data.replace('...','...')
f.write(data)
```

If you use this second option, you should use it in only one bucle so you don't lose the pointer. Hope it helps :)

edit:

As seen in the comments below that maybe the problem is that the pattern is in different lines, adding this line will delete the jump of lines that cuts your pattern

```
data.replace('\n','')#<------
data.replace('the pattern you are looking for', 'the pattern you want instead')
```

Comment: This won't work if the pattern is split on different lines, which is the whole point of the question.

Answer (score -2):

For detecting and replacing multiple occurencies in a text, the function you probably need is this one: [Regex .sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

```py
import re

new_text = None
with open(filepath, mode="r") as f:
  text = f.read()
  text = text.replace('\n', ' ')  # get rid of line jumps
  new_text = re.sub("pattern", "replacement string", text)
```

Comment: This won't work if the pattern is split on different lines, which is the whole point of the question.

Comment: Getting rid of line jumps won't help because of the quotes, and will completely mess the file, making the replacement of the log command where needed impossible.

Comment: yes, this is the problem, the content can be one one line or on multiple line or be on line. I know it starts with the same pattern and end is ")". I don't want to change formatting, so no removal of "\n", tabs or else.